# How to POST raw file using Tornado HTTPRequest

Tags: http, asynchronous, tornado

I want to send some data in POST request using Tornado (AsyncHTTPClient)

```
rec_body = {'source': self.request.body, 'top': str(self.config["top"]), 'model': self.config["model"]}
```

where `self.request.body` is a raw binary file (image).

I try doing this:

```
http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
rec_body = {'source': self.request.body, 'top': str(self.config["top"]), 'model': self.config["model"]}
request = HTTPRequest( url = os.path.join(self.config["dest_addr"], self.config["sub_sect"]) , method='POST', body =rec_body)
result =  http_client.fetch( request, callback=self.handle_request)
```

but got this errors

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/httpclient.py", line 424, in __init__
    self.body = body
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/httpclient.py", line 468, in body
    self._body = utf8(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/escape.py", line 203, in utf8
    "Expected bytes, unicode, or None; got %r" % type(value)
TypeError: Expected bytes, unicode, or None; got <type 'dict'>
ERROR:tornado.access:500 POST /upload (192.168.72.84) 13.14ms
```

What I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I tried curl (naively), requests module all works fine, ut not asynchronously. For tornado`s AsyncHTTPClient there is good [recipe from flickr](https://github.com/bryndin/tornado-flickr-api/blob/master/tornado_flickrapi/multipart.py).

```
Deals with multipart POST requests.
The code is adapted from the recipe found at :
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/146306/
No author name was given.
Author : Alexis Mignon (c)
email  : alexis.mignon@gmail.Com
Date   : 06/08/2011
```

Here is the code:

```py
import mimetypes

from tornado.gen import coroutine, Return
from tornado.httpclient import HTTPRequest

from tornado_flickrapi.httpclient import fetch


@coroutine
def posturl(url, fields, files):
    try:
        response = yield post_multipart(url, fields, files)
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
    raise Return(response)


@coroutine
def post_multipart(url, fields, files):
    """
    Post fields and files to an http host as multipart/form-data.
    fields is a sequence of (name, value) elements for regular form fields.
    files is a sequence of (name, filename, value) elements for data to be
    uploaded as files.
    Return the server's response page.
    """
    content_type, body = encode_multipart_formdata(fields, files)
    headers = {"Content-Type": content_type, 'content-length': str(len(body))}
    request = HTTPRequest(url, "POST", headers=headers, body=body, validate_cert=False)

    try:
        response = yield fetch(request)
    except Exception as e:
        raise e

    raise Return(response)


def encode_multipart_formdata(fields, files):
    """
    fields is a sequence of (name, value) elements for regular form fields.
    files is a sequence of (name, filename, value) elements for data to be
    uploaded as files.
    Return (content_type, body) ready for httplib.HTTP instance
    """
    BOUNDARY = '----------ThIs_Is_tHe_bouNdaRY_$'
    CRLF = '\r\n'
    L = []
    for (key, value) in fields:
        L.append('--' + BOUNDARY)
        L.append('Content-Disposition: form-data; name="%s"' % key)
        L.append('')
        L.append(value)
    for (key, filename, value) in files:
        filename = filename.encode("utf8")
        L.append('--' + BOUNDARY)
        L.append(
            'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="%s"; filename="%s"' % (
                key, filename
            )
        )
        L.append('Content-Type: %s' % get_content_type(filename))
        L.append('')
        L.append(value)
    L.append('--' + BOUNDARY + '--')
    L.append('')
    body = CRLF.join(L)
    content_type = 'multipart/form-data; boundary=%s' % BOUNDARY
    return content_type, body


def get_content_type(filename):
    return mimetypes.guess_type(filename)[0] or 'application/octet-stream'
```